# How to integrate a react widget in a symfony project?

Tags: reactjs, symfony, oauth-2.0

I created my own widget in react (frentend) with my own oAuth2 system for authentication in php (backend), I wanted to know how I could integrate it into a symfony (frentend) project? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To use React with Symfony, you'll have to integrate Webpack in your project: https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html

Once you've enabled the React preset, you'll be able to integrate your components directly in your Twig templates.

I really encourage you to learn more about how Symfony integrates frontend frameworks with these resources:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html
- https://www.twilio.com/blog/building-a-single-page-application-with-symfony-php-and-react
- https://auth0.com/blog/developing-modern-apps-with-symfony-and-react/

Comment: Martin Marx,Thank you very much for your feedback, I will try to follow the tutorial you recommended to me, then, I will tell you if it meets my needs.